# Is listening to a book in which God's voice is imitated forbidden?

Tags: halal-haram, books

I recently bought a copy of *[Inspired By...The Bible Experience: Old Testament](http://www.audible.com/pd/ref=sr_1_3?asin=B002UZZCJW&qid=1349600276&sr=1-3)* from audible.com. One of the things in this recording is that *[Samuel L. Jackson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_L._Jackson)* provides the voice of God. I wonder if it's okay to listen to an audio like this according to Islam?

Comment: What could be the problem with that? Listening to Quran's recitations in many cases is just like listening to God, although the voices now belong to the readers and not Allah Himself. The only problem is when a fake is stated on behalf of God, or the reading style is not as proper as it should be, not polite and etc.

Comment: It's totally forbidden , it's even forbidden to imitate the sound of the prophet, it's very disrespectful to GOD

Comment: This question is not very clear. Are you saying that some guy who is human, is able to imitate the voice of Allaah? I don't think that's anywhere possible. Please clarify your question.

Comment: This is subject to the way the audio is performed. If every being is impersonated by an actor voice, i.e sort of making it like a (theater) play, and God is impersonated by the voice of Samuel L. Jackson, then that is (AFAIK) forbidden as impersonating God is of course forbidden. That is not like reading Quran.

Comment: Still, it's also subject to discussion because The now Bible is not the real bible and the words in it are not the words of Allah. So one may argue that impersonating these words is not impersonating Allah.

Answer (score 1):

```
               In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful
```

There mustn't be a problem if it is done with positive aims (such as conveying some message of Allah to people). On the other hand, it ought not to be funny or mocking.

For instance, I think it could be like reciting the Holy Qur'an, since anyhow this is the words of Allah, and many people recite this. Thus we cannot say that it is a Haram act just because they are imitation of Allah words. Rationally, the significant point is related to Niyyah (intention), and if its intention is positive, then it won't be Haram, like reciting the Holy Qur'an.